# My Alexa Skill is giving me a difficult error, which I do not know the source of

Tags: javascript, error-handling, alexa-skills-kit

I am making a project for my school in JavaScript. I am trying to code an Alexa skill which allows for students to receive information about their teacher's availabilities. I am a novice, and I am trying to resolve an error in which it is saying "Expected "," but saw "i" right before the if statement on Line 423. When I try to add a comma on line 421, it moves the error to that line. I cannot remove the error unless I delete the entire if statement. The if statement is to test where my skill will allow for an emission of a response from Alexa. Thank you for any help I receive!

Below is the code.

```
    {
  "languageModel": {
    "types": [
      {
        "name": "teacher",
        "values": [
          {
            "id": "teacherTyrrell",
            "name": {
              "value": "Dr. Tyrrell",
              "synonyms": [
                "Mrs. Tee-Rull",
                "Ms. Tee-Rull",
                "Maygrace Tee-Rull",
                "Dr. Tee-rull",
                "Ms. Tyrrell",
                "Miss Tyrrell",
                "Mrs. Tyrrell",
                "Marygrace Tyrrell"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "teacherTwyford",
            "name": {
              "value": "Mr. Twyford",
              "synonyms": [
                "Marcus Twyford"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "teacherThornberry",
            "name": {
              "value": "Miss Thornberry",
              "synonyms": [
                "Chantal Thornberry",
                "Mrs. Thornberry",
                "Chantal"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "teacherSuarez",
            "name": {
              "value": "Mrs. Suarez",
              "synonyms": [
                "Miss Suarez",
                "Angela Suarez",
                "Señora Suarez"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "teacherRobtaille",
            "name": {
              "value": "Mrs. Robataille",
              "synonyms": [
                "Señora Robitaille",
                "Patricia Robe-a-tye",
                "Patricia Robitaille",
                "Señora Robe-a-tye",
                "Mrs. Robe-a-tye"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "teacherPhillips",
            "name": {
              "value": "Miss Phillips",
              "synonyms": [
                "Catherine Phillips",
                "Ms. Phillips",
                "Mrs. Phillips"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "teacherPeterson",
            "name": {
              "value": "Mr. Peterson",
              "synonyms": [
                "Eric Peterson"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "teacherNeugebauer",
            "name": {
              "value": "Mr. Neugebauer",
              "synonyms": [
                "Dan Noogabower",
                "Dan Neugebauer",
                "Mr. Noogabower"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "teacherMiller",
            "name": {
              "value": "Mr. Miller",
              "synonyms": [
                "Brock Miller"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "teacherMcGivern",
            "name": {
              "value": "Mr. McGivern",
              "synonyms": [
                "Chucky Mcgivern",
                "Charles McGivern",
                "Chucky",
                "McGivern"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "teacherMcCall",
            "name": {
              "value": "Dr. McCall",
              "synonyms": [
                "Jeremiah McCall",
                "Mr. McCall",
                "D-Mac"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "teacherLichtySmith",
            "name": {
              "value": "Miss Lichty-Smith",
              "synonyms": [
                "Carole Lichty-Smith",
                "Mrs. Lichty-Smith",
                "Ms. L",
                "Mrs. L"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "teacherKim",
            "name": {
              "value": "Miss Kim",
              "synonyms": [
                "Jesse Kim",
                "The health teacher",
                "Mrs. Kim"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "teacherKairet",
            "name": {
              "value": "Dr. Kairet",
              "synonyms": [
                "mrs. curray",
                "miss curray",
                "mrs. kairet",
                "Miss kairet",
                "madame kairet",
                "madame curray",
                "Madame currae"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "teacherHecker",
            "name": {
              "value": "Dr. Hecker",
              "synonyms": [
                "Jeanette Hecker",
                "Miss Hecker",
                "Madame Hecker",
                "Mrs. Hecker"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "teacherFranzosa",
            "name": {
              "value": "Dr. Franzosa",
              "synonyms": [
                "Mr. Franzosa",
                "Jonathon Franzosa",
                "D-Fran"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "teacherFossett",
            "name": {
              "value": "Mr. Fossett",
              "synonyms": [
                "Peter Fossett"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "tecaherFloyd",
            "name": {
              "value": "Miss Floyd",
              "synonyms": [
                "Deborah Floyd",
                "Ms. Floyd",
                "Mrs. Floyd"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "teacherFaulhaber",
            "name": {
              "value": "Mr. Faulhaber",
              "synonyms": [
                "Gregory Faulhaber",
                "G-Faul"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "teacherTDunn",
            "name": {
              "value": "Mr. Dunn",
              "synonyms": [
                "The GOAT",
                "Timothy Dunn",
                "T-Dunn"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "teacherPDunn",
            "name": {
              "value": "Mrs. Dunn",
              "synonyms": [
                "P-Dunn",
                "Miss Dunn",
                "Patricia Dunn"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "teacherDestin",
            "name": {
              "value": "Dr. Destin",
              "synonyms": [
                "Yven Destin",
                "Mr. Destin"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "teacherDahl",
            "name": {
              "value": "Mr. Dahl",
              "synonyms": [
                "Matthew Dahl"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "teacherLChristiansen",
            "name": {
              "value": "Mrs. Christiansen",
              "synonyms": [
                "Laura Christiansen"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "teacherJChristiansen",
            "name": {
              "value": "Mr. Christiansen",
              "synonyms": [
                "John Christiansen"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "teacherCastro",
            "name": {
              "value": "Mrs. Castro",
              "synonyms": [
                "Mrs. Castro",
                "Malena Castro",
                "Señora Castro"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "teacherButler",
            "name": {
              "value": "Mrs. Butler",
              "synonyms": [
                "Miss Butler",
                "Paula Butler"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "teacherBrand",
            "name": {
              "value": "Ms. Brand",
              "synonyms": [
                "Amy Brand",
                "Mrs. Brand",
                "Miss Brand"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "teacherBodollo",
            "name": {
              "value": "Mrs. Bodollo",
              "synonyms": [
                "Lisa Bodollo",
                "Miss Bodollo"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "teacherBlack",
            "name": {
              "value": "Mr. Black",
              "synonyms": [
                "Merle Black",
                "Merle"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "teacherBack",
            "name": {
              "value": "Mrs. Back",
              "synonyms": [
                "Jamie Back"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "intents": [
      {
        "name": "AMAZON.CancelIntent",
        "samples": []
      },
      {
        "name": "AMAZON.HelpIntent",
        "samples": []
      },
      {
        "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
        "samples": []
      },
      {
        "name": "dailySchedule",
        "samples": [
          "What is the bell schedule",
          "What's the schedule today",
          "What is the schedule today"
        ],
        "slots": []
      },
      {
        "name": "teacherFreeBell",
        "samples": [
          "Is {teacher} free ",
          "Is {teacher} free right now",
          "What free bells does {teacher} have today",
          "What free bells does {teacher} have",
          "When is {teacher} free"
        ],
        "slots": [
          {
            "name": "teacher",
            "type": "teacher"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "whatBell",
        "samples": [
          "What bell is it",
          "What bell is right now"
        ],
        "slots": []
      }
    ],
    "invocationName": "country day"
  },
  "prompts": [
    {
      "id": "Elicit.Intent-teacherFreeBell.IntentSlot-teacher",
      "variations": [
        {
          "type": "PlainText",
          "value": "Which teacher are you asking about?"
        },
        {
          "type": "PlainText",
          "value": "Who is the teacher?"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "dialog": {
    "intents": [
      {
        "name": "teacherFreeBell",
        "confirmationRequired": false,
        "prompts": {},
        "slots": [
          {
            "name": "teacher",
            "type": "teacher",
            "elicitationRequired": true,
            "confirmationRequired": false,
            "prompts": {
              "elicitation": "Elicit.Intent-teacherFreeBell.IntentSlot-teacher"
            }
            if IntentSlot(teacher) = teacherBack
            {
              this.emit("this is working")
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

https://pastebin.com/VyctHsbS

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have an if statement inside the schema json

If you'd like to test where the skill will allow for an emission do it in the skill code.
Your skill needs to have an end point for you to send a reponse to the user, you can do that with your [own service](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/host-a-custom-skill-as-a-web-service.html), or use a [lambda function](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/host-a-custom-skill-as-an-aws-lambda-function.html)

** for more information on skill schemas check the [alexa documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/interaction-model-schema.html)

Comment: Thank you so much!